# Spark: Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

Using spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6
According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

I can set the heap size with **spark.executor.memory** which is **--executor-memory** from spark-submit

When running my job the executor memory doesn't exceed the allocated memory yet I receive the error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I am submitting my job with:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main \
  --master spark://ec2-52-23-155-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 27G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /root/final_project/phenotyping_w_anchors_161-assembly-1.0.jar \
  1000
```

I am using 2 *m4.2xlarge* instances (32.0 GB, 8 cores)

Answer (score 11):

The issue was there was not enough memory being allocated to the driver.
By default it was being allocated 1024.0 MB

I specified 3GB (probably too much) by adding

> --driver-memory 3g

Example

```
./bin/spark-submit \
    --class edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main \
    --master spark://ec2-52-23-155-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066   \
    --deploy-mode cluster   \
    --executor-memory 27G   \
    --driver-memory 3g \
    /root/final_project/phenotyping_w_anchors_161-assembly-1.0.jar   \
    1000
```